# Getting an int from a DataTable DataRow when strings normally appear

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have searched extensively for an answer here and elsewhere but have had little success.

I am using OLEDB to connect to a spreadsheet and extract data to port to a database, and all is going fairly smoothly except one minor detail.

There is a column called Skills where the entry I receive is usually a string, however the value can sometimes be an int like 334423, when I try to add this value to the new database, the entry is simply blank.

Usual approach to extracting:

```
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
      /* dealing with other columns */

      sTemp.skill = dr[3].ToString();

      /* more stuff */

    }
```

But I get absolutely no response when the column in this row is an int, just a blank string. It doesn't even throw any exceptions, which would at least give me some direction.

I also tried casting it as an int:

```
sTemp.skill = (int)dr[3].ToString();
```

(which didn't work)

FYI: "sTemp" is an object with strings associated with it, skill being a string. The mysteriously quiet nature of this problem also makes it hard for me to know what I should be asking. Any OLEDB gurus out there, please help! Thanks

**EDIT:** After some more investigation, it seems that the problem was not with conversion/casting of strings to ints, but actually getting the data in the first place.

In the instance of a field having a number, it will totally ignore it (for reasons I cannot think of), so there is nothing to parse. Mysterious behaviour indeed.

Unless anyone knows of known problems getting ints from excel using an OleDbDataAdapter, then feel free to answer... Sorry to have wasted your time all, how embarrassing.

**EDIT #2:** Here is an updated code view:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace SQEPSkillsImporter
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        string skillsFileName = "";
        List<SkillTemplate> TemplateList = new List<SkillTemplate>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void skillsFilePathBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.skillsFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Worksheets|*.xls;*xlsx";
            DialogResult result = skillsFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.skillsFileName = skillsFileDialog.FileName;
                skillsFilePathTxBx.Text = skillsFileName;
            }
        }

        private void readSkillsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable skillsTable = new DataTable("SkillsResults");

            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" +
                " Data Source=" + this.skillsFileName +
                ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

            using(OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                Connection.Open();

                using(OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    Command.Connection = Connection;
                    /* The columns I want are in A through D */
                    Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Skills$A:D]";

                    using (OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        Adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
                        Adapter.Fill(skillsTable);
                    }
                }
                Connection.Close();
                Connection.Dispose();
            }
            SkillTemplate sTemp = new SkillTemplate();
            foreach (DataRow dr in skillsTable.Rows)
            {
                /* most sGroup, group and heading columns are blank, so remain the same unless changed, meaning the name wont be null */
                if(dr[0].ToString() != "")
                    sTemp.SuperGroup = dr[0].ToString();
                if (dr[1].ToString() != "")
                    sTemp.Group = dr[1].ToString();
                if (dr[2].ToString() != "")
                    sTemp.Heading = dr[2].ToString();
                if (dr[3].ToString() != "")
                    sTemp.Skill = dr[3].ToString();

                /* VERY rough test textbox to verify that my output is correct before sending to DB */
                this.skillsDumpTxBx.Text += sTemp.SuperGroup + " /// " + sTemp.Group + " /// " + sTemp.Heading + " /// " + sTemp.Skill + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
    }

    public class SkillTemplate
    {
        public string SuperGroup { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(int)dr[3].ToString();` cannot work but this would: `int.Parse(dr[3].ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

```
sTemp.skill = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3].ToString());
```

or use this method to convert to any type:

```
/// <summary>
/// Safe converting to any type
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="value">Value to convert</param>
/// <param name="defaultValue">Default value, sets type of return value</param>
/// <returns>Converted value or defaul when error</returns>
public static T safeConvert<T>(object value, T defaultValue)
{
    try
    {
        return value == null ? default(T) : 
            (T)Convert.ChangeType( value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T) );
    }
    catch
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
sTemp.skill = safeConvert(dr[3],0);
// or
String s = safeConvert(obj, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

If dr[3].ToString() is returning you blank then possibilities are it contains DBNull or blank string. Did you check your query to make sure your 4 th column (zero based index 3) is returning a valid value

Comment: After rummaging around I discovered that no entry is given to my DataRow when a number is there, so I have to find out why this is.

My command is very simple:
    Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Skills$A:D]";

Comment: Phoenix you need to show more code than you have listed above edit your post to reflect the true issue which sounds to be an issue with the connectionString

Comment: I have updated the question regarding this, I am not too experienced with dealing with this kind of stuff...